# Пропорциональное изменение размера div блока

Tags: jquery

При нажатии на кнопку добавляется div  блок, при растягивании передаю два параметра maxHeight,maxWidth, как мне ограничить растягиваемую область исходя из площади? т.е. к примеру площадь 2400 а высота и ширина 60/40, получается дальше этих размеров я растягивать не могу, но если при растягивании уменьшаю ширину то соответственно я могу растягивать в высоту,пока у меня получилось что дальше текущего размера я растянуть не могу.
[Вот Код](http://yadi.sk/d/22YuPcrrBwhcc)

Comment: @MaxOnn, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: function resize(id,s){
$(document).on("mousemove", function () {
var width = $(id).outerWidth();
var height= $(id).outerHeight();
var result;
mHeight=s/width;
mWidth=s/height;
$(id).resizable({maxHeight:mHeight,maxWidth:mWidth, stop: function(event, ui) { alert("mHeight="+height+"mWidth="+width) } });
});}